# Create Unit Tests is supported only within a public class or a public method VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting a ***Create Unit Tests is supported only within a public class or a public method*** when I try to create unit tests for my app.  I was trying to test a public method in a very simple app in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Here's the Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Scratch
{
    public class Program    //Originally this was just class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");

        }

        public static string TruncateOld(string value, int length)
        {
            string result = value;
            if (value != null) // Skip empty string check for elucidation
            {
                result = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string Truncate(string value, int length)
        {
            return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
        }

    }
}
```

I've found this [msdn article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc8bfaa4-1c4e-4686-b83f-9037e49a4b5a/create-unit-tests-not-working-vs-professional-2015-c?forum=vsunittest), but it doesn't really offer any suggestions on how to solve the problem.  Also, I've never installed 'ALM Rangers Generate Unit Test.'

I got rid of everything from my Program.cs except for the Main and added a new Public Class1 with the following code (I still get the error and the menu goes away):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scratch
{
    public class Class1
    {


        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public string TruncateOld(string value, int length)
        {
            string result = value;
            if (value != null) // Skip empty string check for elucidation
            {
                result = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
            }
            return result;
        }

        public string Truncate(string value, int length)
        {
            return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Does reopening the solution work? It should bring back the menu item according to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc8bfaa4-1c4e-4686-b83f-9037e49a4b5a/create-unit-tests-not-working-vs-professional-2015-c?forum=vsunittest. (see the reply of Pratap Lakshman [MSFT at Thursday, August 27, 2015 7:47 AM)

Comment: It does bring it back, until the next time I try to add unit tests, then it just goes away again.

Comment: I would be interested if anyone else can reproduce this.  It's hard to believe that it's impossible to add unit tests to such a trivial program.  I can zip up the entire solution and put it somewhere.  All I did was to create a new console app, add a ref to the UnitTestFramework, add the attached code for Program.cs and then try to add a unit test.

Comment: I would post this in that forum. More MS officials there. Probably a bug.

Comment: I've just tested it on my machine. I don't have this problem. I have also the enterprise edition.

Comment: Weird, here's my version info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01590

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-80000-00000-AA932
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools
    
UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Visual Basic 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA932
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA932
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Comment: I've posted to that thread in the MS forum including the fully Visual Studio information that is truncated above.

Comment: Ever get this figured out?

I have the same issue with a Web API 2 Project / Solution that I'm running in VS 2015.

The kicker is that I have another Web API 2 Project / Solution that I'm running in VS 2015 and it is working just fine!

Comment: As I recall I just created a new blank solution in Visual Studio, copied my code over there and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference of the testframework from your project?
Dont ask me why, but it solved the same issue for me...

Comment: You should follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022 :)

Answer (score 15):

To anyone that is new to C# having this issue, you need to add the **public** keyword to your class.

For example,

```
class myProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

You'd need to change the first line to `public class myProgram`

Comment: Not sure this is the correct answer for the question (he has "public") but for the message, which I also have, it worked.

Comment: Yeah, that was my hope, was that some newer people would wind up here, and this would save them some time.

Answer (score 4):

So I know this is late, and not really an answer to the above question due to your class definition, but I don't see enough forums on this error, so I decided to add my findings here.

I found that if you have a class with only properties and no true methods, 'Create Unit Tests' will not work. Even if your properties are public and have complex getters or setters. Here was the state of my code when running into this problem, as I just made the class:

```
namespace some.Namespace
{
   using some.Namespace.Interfaces;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class SomeData : ISomeData
   {
      public bool SomeFlag => throw new NotImplementedException();

      public Dictionary<string, string> SomeFields => throw new NotImplementedException();

      public Dictionary<string, string> SomeOtherFields => throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

However, you can work around this by either defining at least constructor or by temporarily making some random method. However, note that tests will only be made for true methods in your class so you will still have to manually write the tests for your properties' getters/setters.

Hope someone finds this answer helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Probably coming to the party too late, but since I had the same problem and was able to solve it, you never know who is going to need it. So... as soon as I removed the reference to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`
the "Create Unit Tests" option reappeared in the context menu and I was able to create the tests I needed.

Comment: True. VS seems to interpret the assembly as test assembly, when this is referenced. Also the warning is misleading: the class must be public AND have at minimum one public method, else it will also fail.

Comment: At least one public method is key.  Method-less classes will give the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is still a rabbit hole to fall into, as I stepped into it today. In my case, running on VS 2019 Enterprise. My error was having NuGet packages installed on the test project which isn't needed. I had added NuGet packages MSTest.TestAdapter, and Microsoft.TestPlatform. Removing both, closing and reopening the IDE restored the wizard for creating a Test Method. For an initial or new test project, the only NuGet package needed for getting started is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the built in Visual Studio 2015 test cases, you need to take out the static from the public members. Like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Testing_01()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue( [some bool condition] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (see the last code snippet), but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I've just tested it with a new winforms project with net framework 4.0, and it worked. It created a new project with the same name ending with "Tests" with the skeletton of the truncateOld test method.

If it doesn't work, try creating the project manually like the code I posted, maybe there is an assembly that is not getting referenced correctly.

Comment: I rebooted and created a new console solution and I got the error when I tried to add a unit test, but the menu item didn't go away.  I created a new public class and was able to create a Unit test project as expected.  What I don't understand is that I didn't add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework to my solution so I'm kind of surprised that it works.

Comment: I always create the tests projects manually because it helps me understand when things go wrong. Check out the Test Explorer pane if you haven't already, the test methods should appear there and if they appear and run, then you probably don't need anything else.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as written in this post, and none of the solutions have worked for me. I even tried creating a new project with nothing but "Public <classname>" and a single "public <methodname>". Same problem, except now "create unit tests" won't even show up.